# How do I create a data access layer that talks to git on a git server?

Tags: git, api-design, git-server

#### Problem

I want to create a personal micro-Github on a server, but how does one talk to git on the server in an elegant manner? Would it be wise to the send commands to the git-shell using PHP's [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec)? Would I be talking to git directly? To understand the idea, let's talk about it for a few seconds.

#### How it should work

The idea is that I want to create a GitHub-like application that will allow users to manage multiple repositories and browse repositories. It will be required that git is installed on the server for it to become a [git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server). And in order to allow the aforementioned GitHub-like features, I imagine that I should wrap git in an API layer which shall serve as a data-access layer. This way, the application may use git to do git things, and shall allow the application to accomplish useful things:

*Please note: language choice is not limited to PHP. I only used PHP because of its `exec()` function which helps to highlight to the questions in this case.*

```php
// Instantiate a git object
$git = new Git();

// Connect to a git server
$result = $git->connect("0.0.0.0","username","password");

// Create a bare repository in the filesystem
$repo = $git->init("name","/home/pwd/user/name.git");

// Clone a repository
$repo->clone("username","host","repository")

// Commit to the repository
$repo->commit($fileset,"message","long message");
```

#### Question

The question becomes this: beneath the `Git` objects and abstraction,  how would I talk to git on the server? Would I be sending commands to the git-shell using PHP's [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec)? Is there another way that I can speak with git elegantly?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the right place to talk about design abstractions (maybe softwareengineering.stackexchange.com?). But note that Git itself is designed with two kinds (or sub-groups or whatever) of commands: *porcelain* commands are meant for talking to users, and *plumbing* commands are meant for use by other programs. So you'd mostly want to use plumbing commands and parse their output. Alternatively, consider using a lower level interface in Python (several Git libraries), or libgit2 (C? C++? C#? I haven't looked), or the Go version of Git.

Comment: @torek OK thanks for point out what stackoverflow is for, and thanks for helping me with the question. Your suggestions are really helpful. Really interested in Go for Git. Thanks man, really.